# why I can't save value in my assembly matrix_product code?

Tags: assembly, machine-learning, x86-64

It took me a lots of time for finding why I can't store values in void *C. In this code, I can call dot_prod to calculate the dot product in the inner loop, and in case of overflow, I use another func which is mod, takes 2 arguments, one is the return value of dot_prod, another one is 17, which is mod(%rax,17). In my code, I can print my matrix source A, B, but I don't know why my code can't calculate the matrix product of A, B and the details is in the below I have one problem is I can display the matrix A,B, but I can not store the output of A,B which stored in C in register %rcx

```
and my output looks like:
 5 b a 3
 a 6 2 1
 6 3 e d
 8 5 2 0

 a c e 5
 c a 1 1
 c 0 c a
 c 0 1 a

 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
```

Here value in third matrix is 0, but it is not my expect, in matrix C it should be the matrix product of A and B

```
.globl matrix_prod
    matrix_prod:            # void matrix_prod(void *A, void *B, void *C, int n);
            #for i from 0 to n-1 do
                #for j from 0 to n-1 do
                    #C[i][j] = mod(dot_prod(A, B, n, i, j), 17)
            # long dot_prod(void *A, void *B, int n, int i, int j);
    # %rdx: void *C
    # %rdi: A
    # %rsi: B
    # %rcx: n
    movq $-1, %r9    #i
    movq $0, %r8     #j
    movq %rcx, %r11  #save n value 
    movq $0, %rcx    #recycle rcx

outerloop:
    incq %r9   #i++
    cmpq %r11, %r9 #if i<n
    jge  endloop 

innerloop:
    cmpq %r8, %r11  #if j<n
    jge outerloop
    push %rdx   #C

    movq %r11, %rdx #now n in rdx
    movq %r9, %rcx  #now i in rcx

    call dot_prod

    pop  %rdx   #now c in %rdx

    push %rsi   #B
    push %rdi   #A


    movq %rax, %rdi
    movq $17, %rsi

    call mod

    movq %rax, (%rdx)
    addq $8,  %rdx

    pop  %rdi   #now rdi=A
    pop  %rsi   #now rsi=B

    incq %r8  #j++
    jmp  innerloop
endloop:
    ret
```

Comment: `mod` is allowed to destroy `%rdx` (at least according to the standard x86-64 System V calling convention which you're using for the rest of your code), but you're using it right after the function call.  Single-step your code with a debugger and watch register values change.

Comment: Hint: save/restore some call-preserved registers, like `%rbx`, `%rbp`, and `%r12-%r15`, at the start/end of your function, and use them for variables that should survive the function calls.  Using some `mov` or `lea` (or anything else) instructions to copy or compute function args in arg-passing registers is easier to read and more efficient than push/popping stuff inside your inner loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes thx